# Invalid syntax in path when changing directory

Tags: python, directory, dir, cd

In Python, first I check where I am:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

This gives me `%run C:/Users/<name>/Desktop/<script.py>`
Now I want to change where I am:

```
os.chdir("C:/Users/<name>/Desktop/")
```

This gives me

```
%run C:/Users/<name>/Desktop/<script.py>
  File "C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\<script.py>", line 3
    os.chdir("/C:/Users/<name>/Desktop/")
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried variations of this but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The path is invalid,for windows the path should look like this `C:\\path\\to\\file`

Comment: @enginefree I think the direction of slashes doesn't matter, I think Python converts them. Additionally, I doubt that would cause a SyntaxError.

Comment: @PetarGyurov What's the full code?

Comment: What I meant was, the `/` before `C:` thats why its giving the syntax error. Thats an invalid path.

Comment: What's the `%run` all about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you can do this including:

Using os.path to join a path and an environment variable:

```
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('userprofile'),'Desktop'))
```

You could alternatively use either double backslashes (backslash needs to be escaped in Python strings):

```
os.chdir('c:\\users\\prosserc\\desktop')
```

or use a raw string:

```
os.chdir(r'c:\users\prosserc\desktop')
```

I would recommend the first option as it does require a hard coded user name.

Comment: I tried all the ways you suggested. The first one gave me an error and the other two didn't do anyting; ie: the directory is still the same.

Comment: I do not get an error when running the first one. What does the error message say? For the other two what directory are you in before running the command?

Comment: It's a very long one but the type is `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`
Before I run it I am in C:/Users/Petar/Desktop/script.py

Comment: I have assume from the paths that you were using you are on Windows (Vista or after), is this correct? Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows7. I am not sure what the Python version is (I am new to this). From the language selection in my script editor there is Python and Python 3. I use Python.

Comment: okay and if you just run `print os.getenv('userprofile')` do you still get an error?

Comment: I get `%run C:/Users/Petar/Desktop/PS3_Ex2`
`None`

Comment: So no error, just lists the directory I am in (which weirdly ends with the script name) and then it says None

Comment: Okay, the output that you are seeing there is not the output from the command that I gave, something else must be causing this output. What environment are you using to run Python? Try just from the command line i.e. open a cmd window enter `python` to get the interpretor and then paste in the command that I gave. If just `python` does not work to open the interpretor then you need to either use the full path to your python.exe or add this directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I am using Enthought Canopy. I ran the cmd. Same error as before pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do code like this:

```
path = "full path to your directory"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
#some code
```